# Unable to run a VBA Macro on other PCs

Tags: excel, vba, path, directory

I am looking for help with a part of my VBA code. It runs without any problem on few PCs, but when it comes to mine it does not work at all. No error returned. If anybody see something that could be wrong please let me know.

```
fn = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*.xl*")
Do While ((fn <> "") And (Not (fn Like "*Inside*")))

    Range("B4").value = fn

    Call setCorrectValues

    fn = Dir()
Loop
```

Comment: If all the input conditions are right (i.e., you have some *.xl* files in the same folder than your macro containing the word "Inside"), the only reason I can come up with is the Drive where you are executing the macro: is it the drive where MS Office is installed? (C: for instance)

Comment: can you show code for the `setCorrectValues` sub?

Answer (score 0):

Recently got into trouble with the damn Dir function. Try this:

```
Dim objFSO As Variant
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim FolderName As String
FolderName = ThisWorkbook.Path

Dim objFolder As Variant
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(FolderName)
Debug.Print objFolder.Path

Dim objFiles As Variant
Set objFiles = objFolder.Files
Dim objFile As Variant
For Each objFile In objFiles
    Debug.Print objFile.Name
    If Not (fn Like "*Inside*.xls") Then
        Range("B4").Value = fn
        Call setCorrectValues
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```